# Do we need to pass all the detections from a object detection model or filtered detections based on confidence threshold for calculation of mAP?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am working on evaluating the multiple object detection models. I am getting a list of detections from pre-trained models and then I have to provide the detections to another library which will calculate the mAP. My question is whether do I need to first filter out the list of detections and then provide it to the library for mAP calculations? or it's necessary to send all the detections without filtering it, so that mAP calculations are accurate.

For explaining it clearly, providing the below example.

```
format of list elements - (class, box, score)
detections = [(c1, b1, 0.90), (c1, b2, 0.85), (c1, b2, 0.45)] //total 3 elements
filtered_detections = [(c1, b1, 0.90), (c1, b2, 0.85)] // score > confidence_threshold, lets say 0.5

mAP1 = calculate_mAP(ground_truth, detections)
mAP2 = calculate_mAP(ground_truth, filtered_detections)
```

How the mAP1 and mAP2 will be different? let's consider PASCAL VOC implementation for mAP here.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question to filter out the objects or not first, let me tell you how mAP calculation is done in the case of PASCAL VOC Challenge.

As you know, mAP uses Intersection Over Union(IOU), Precision(P), and Recall(R) which are calculated based on the number of true positives(TP), false positives(FP), and false negatives(FN).

In the setting of mAP calculation for Object Detection of the Pascal VOC Challenge, the TP, FP, and FN are defined as follows:

TP: Predicted Bounding Boxes (BB) of detections whose (IoU) with the ground truth (GT) is above 0.5.

FP: Predicted Bounding Boxes whose IoU with GT is below 0.5

FN: Those objects which do not have a predicted bounding box.

Now the object detection model will assign a confidence score to each of its predicted BB for a given class.

Suppose you have an object with 3 bounding box predictions with different confidence scores. The mAP calculation method sorts the bounding boxes with decreasing confidence scores and the first object is considered as true positive based on the overlap criterion and the remaining two as false positives.

Refer to the link for a better understanding
[The PASCAL Visual Object Classes (VOC) Challenge](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/postscript/ijcv_voc09.pdf)

Coming to your question, as you can see that the bounding boxes are sorted based on the confidence scores for calculating the TP's and FP's, the PASCAL VOC Challenge mAP metrics does not filter out any of the detections. It considers all the bounding boxes the model generates.

Check out the below github link on how the mAP metrics for Pascal VOC is calculated
[Pascal VOC Object Detection metrics by Rafael Padilla](https://github.com/rafaelpadilla/Object-Detection-Metrics)

From your question, PASCAL VOC Challenge used mAP1 evaluator because in the challenge it was expected that the model filters out the detections beforehand.

In general, we use mAP2 for evaluating an object detection model. Score thresholding or filtering out objects is necessary before evaluating your model for a generic use case.

I hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your supplying two lists with different number of elements.  If "calculate_mAP" calculates the mean using all elements, for example, then mAP1 ≠ mAP2.